# Laravel is returning the first result of stored procedure

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedures

I have a custom procedure in my database that calls two other procedures. When I execute the procedure in MySQL it shows the results of both procedures as expected. However when I call my stored procedure in **Laravel** it is only returning the result of the first procedure.

This is how I am calling my procedure in Laravel:

`DB::select("CALL my_procedure");`

I also even tried calling it like this:

`DB::select(DB::raw("CALL my_procedure");`

`my_procedure` contains the following query:

```
BEGIN
CALL procedure_one();
CALL procedure_two();
END
```

`procedure_one` and `procedure_two` are simple select statements.

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example in which you can call a procedure with parameters:

```
$result = DB::statement('call fill_stats_temp(?,?,?)', [$academic_year,$reference_date,$academic_period]);
```

Try to call `my_procedure` with the above statement. So the code would be:

```
$result = DB::statement('call my_procedure');
```

Comment: Hi Tinxuanna, thanks for the welcome. The DB::statement functions returns a boolean which does not suit my case :( I want the result of the procedures to be stored in my variable so I can send them to the user. I was thinking about calling the database twice. Not very optimal but it works since I have no other solution